# automatic way to detect objects passed by value to functions in c++

Tags: c++

I and my co-coder often forget to pass (large) objects by reference and instead pass by value. This might be hurting performance. Is it possible to configure the compiler to warn me in such cases? Is it possible to detect it automatically in a bunch of c++ source files ... maybe a regex that someone has already written?

UPDATE:
Thanks guys for your helpful answers. One problem with all answers is that they only work for classes I write ... not for existing classes .. like `std::vector` . I can subclass them, but it would be too tedious

Comment: Using a regex definitely isn't the right tool. Even if you could identify arguments that aren't passed by reference, it's not helpful without knowing how large those types are. I don't have a specific answer, but I suggest looking at static code analysis tools.

Comment: You could disable the copy constructors on you large objects.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0_beta1/libs/utility/utility.htm#Class_noncopyable

Answer (score 3):

You could declare the copy constructor for the types as `private` - since the copy ctor is called when passing objects by value, your code will error at compile time at any call-site where you're passing by value.

You can also use the new `c++11` support to `delete` unwanted constructors/destructors, if your compiler supports it. Check out the details [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#default).

If you actually need to use the copy ctor in your code another option is to add a debug break-point within the copy ctor. You can then step through a debug build of your program and check when the copy ctor is called.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Since you're looking to detect copy-ctor use on the standard containers things are a little less straightforward. You could try something along [these](http://ideone.com/8CcRd) lines, which is a super-ugly hack, delegating all `std::vector` instances through a wrapper class with a disabled copy-ctor.

Note the warnings in the code. I would only use this kind of thing to identify your pass-by-value issues and then delete it - reverting to clean use of `std::vector` etc.

If you wanted to permanently disable copying of standard containers you could write your own wrapper classes that encapsulate (rather than inherit from) the standard containers.

Comment: is there something that works for existing classes .. like `std::vector` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it.  Making wrappers is a good idea . But I was wondering if something less tedious can be done

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do is have your heavy object inherit from class like:

```
struct heavy {
    struct heavy_copy_ctor_invoked {};
    heavy(const heavy&) {
        typename boost::mpl::print<heavy_copy_ctor_invoked>::type _;
    }
};

struct foo : heavy { ...
```

everytime heavy copy-ctor is called, mpl will throw a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a copy constructor and an operator=  of the big object private. In QT they made special macro for that  Q_DISABLE_COPY().